# Error when trying to label x and y axis in Pandas horizontal bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to set x and y labels on my horizontal bar graph, but I get this error. Please help me through it.

This is my code for the graph:

```
alt_method[['Jan_avg','Jan_count']].sort_values(by=['Jan_avg','Jan_count'],ascending=True).plot.barh(xlim = (0,60000),ylim = (6300.0,64289.0))

alt_method.set_xlabel('Shipment')
```

and this is my error message:

> `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alt_method` is a DataFrame. You can use `.plot()` to plot the DataFrame, but to set an axis label, you should use the plotting commands available via `matplotlib.pyplot` (commonly abbreviated to `plt`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.plot() # per your code
plt.ylabel('ylabel goes here')
plt.show()
```

A reproducible example:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/fpp2/goog200.csv", index_col=0)
df['value'].plot()
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to grab the axis handle returned by the `plot` and then set the label as

```
ax = alt_method[['Jan_avg','Jan_count']].sort_values(by=['Jan_avg','Jan_count'],ascending=True).plot.barh(xlim = (0,60000),ylim = (6300.0,64289.0))

ax.set_xlabel('Shipment')
```